# Guava Optional.of(Optional.of(user)) get() returns class Present

Tags: java, guava, option-type

After inheriting some code I am experiencing an issue whereby when calling `public T get()` on `class Present<T> extends Optional<T>` it is returning a reference of Optional.of(Optional.of(user)) of class type Present and not the 'user' reference object.

A previous deployed branch of the code returns Optional.of(user) which is a reference to the 'user' that is required.

The previous deployed branch is using guava-bundle-19.0 and the newer broken branch is using guava-bundle-21.0. I have tried a couple of approaches to get to the 'user' reference but always get class of type Present returned.

Some pointers as to how I can resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards, Ian

Comment: It's probably a bug in your code, not in the library. Could you post your (currently not working) code here?

Comment: Write a test case. Three lines like `class User {}; User user = new User(); assertEquals(user, Optional.of(user).get());` would be much better than your explanation. +++ Anyway, Guava's `Optional` was implemented using its `Present` and `Absent` subclasses.

Comment: If you have two nested Optionals, then of course you will need to do two calls to get.